# Identity Server 4 with OAuth and ADFS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, oauth-2.0, identityserver4

I am having trouble with using OAuthAuthentication with IS4 and ASPNetCore. Took DamienBod's (thank you) sample Identity Server with AspNetIdentity attempted adding OAuth with windows server 2012 ADFS3. I could authenticate using the external ADFS but not getting correct results on the Identity Server side.
`AccountController.ExternalLoginCallback` : `var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync()` returns NULL and am back to login page.
The following code might have some things that may not make sense as I was experimenting. Right now I almost reached the end of my capabilities as my knowledge in this area is not that great. Any help is very much appreciated
My code files are as follows:

Startup.cs:

`

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
.SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            builder.AddUserSecrets();
        }

        _environment = env;

        builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var cert = new X509Certificate2(Path.Combine(_environment.ContentRootPath, "damienbodserver.pfx"), "");

        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddAuthentication();

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();



        services.AddTransient<IProfileService, IdentityWithAdditionalClaimsProfileService>();

        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
        services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();

    //    services.AddAuthentication();
        //var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
        //{
        //    //options.
        //});

        services.AddDeveloperIdentityServer()
            .SetSigningCredential(cert)
            .AddInMemoryScopes(Config.GetScopes())
            .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
            .AddInMemoryUsers(Config.GetUsers())
            .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
            .AddProfileService<IdentityWithAdditionalClaimsProfileService>();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"D:\Downloads\AspNet5IdentityServerAngularImplicitFlow-master\AspNet5IdentityServerAngularImplicitFlow-master\src\IdentityServerWithIdentitySQLite\signingCertificate.CER");

        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        //app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
        //{
        //    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
        //    AutomaticChallenge = true,
        //    SaveToken = true,
        //    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        //    {
        //        //Iss     
        //        ValidateIssuer = true,
        //        ValidIssuer = "http://FSSTARS-BO-ADFS.linkedgaming.com/adfs/services/trust",
        //        //    ValidIssuer = "7fe2cdc6-4c2d-4d92-bac9-990df31f669c",

        //        ValidateAudience = true,
        //        ValidAudience = "microsoft:identityserver:StarsRelyingTrustProvider",
        //        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,

        //        IssuerSigningKey = new X509SecurityKey(certificate),

        //        ValidateLifetime = true,
        //        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero

        //    },
        //});

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseIdentity();

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme,

            AutomaticAuthenticate = false,
            AutomaticChallenge = false
        });

        app.UseOAuthAuthentication(new OAuthOptions()
        {
            DisplayName = "ADFS",
            //AutomaticAuthenticate = false,
            //AutomaticChallenge = false,
            AuthenticationScheme = "OAuth2",
            SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme,
            SaveTokens = true,

            //ClientId = "7fe2cdc6-4c2d-4d92-bac9-990df31f669c",
            ClientId = "9fe2cdc6-4c2d-4d92-bac9-990df31f669g",
            ClientSecret = "notneeded",
            CallbackPath = new            Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString("/About"),
            AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://fsstars-bo-adfs.linkedgaming.com/adfs/oauth2/authorize",
            TokenEndpoint = "https://fsstars-bo-adfs.linkedgaming.com/adfs/oauth2/token",
            Events = new OAuthEvents
            {
                OnRedirectToAuthorizationEndpoint = context =>
                {
                    context.Response.Redirect($"{context.RedirectUri}&resource=StarsRelyingTrustProvider");
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            },


        });

        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
}
`
```

AccountController.cs:

```
`[Authorize]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
public AccountController(
IIdentityServerInteractionService interaction,
IPersistedGrantService persistedGrantService,
UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
IEmailSender emailSender,
ISmsSender smsSender,
ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
_interaction = interaction;
_persistedGrantService = persistedGrantService;
_userManager = userManager;
_signInManager = signInManager;
_emailSender = emailSender;
_smsSender = smsSender;
_logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<AccountController>();
}
    //
    // GET: /Account/Login
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation(1, "User logged in.");
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
            {
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(SendCode), new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            }
            if (result.IsLockedOut)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning(2, "User account locked out.");
                return View("Lockout");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }


    //
    // POST: /Account/LogOff
    //[HttpPost]
    //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    //public async Task<IActionResult> LogOff()
    //{
    //    await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
    //    _logger.LogInformation(4, "User logged out.");
    //    return RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home");
    //}

    //
    // POST: /Account/ExternalLogin
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        // Request a redirect to the external login provider.
        var redirectUrl = Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
        var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);
        return Challenge(properties, provider);
    }

     //
    // GET: /Account/ExternalLoginCallback
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(
        string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
    {
        if (remoteError != null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, $"Error from external provider: {remoteError}");
            return View(nameof(Login));
        }
        var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (info == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));
        }

        // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login.
        var result = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation(5, "User logged in with {Name} provider.", info.LoginProvider);
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
        if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
        {
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(SendCode), new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
        }
        if (result.IsLockedOut)
        {
            return View("Lockout");
        }
        else
        {
            // If the user does not have an account, then ask the user to create an account.
            ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
            ViewData["LoginProvider"] = info.LoginProvider;
            var email = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
            return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel { Email = email });
        }
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/ExternalLoginConfirmation
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginConfirmation(ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Get the information about the user from the external login provider
            var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
            if (info == null)
            {
                return View("ExternalLoginFailure");
            }
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                result = await _userManager.AddLoginAsync(user, info);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                    _logger.LogInformation(6, "User created an account using {Name} provider.", info.LoginProvider);
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                }
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        return View(model);
    }

    // GET: /Account/ConfirmEmail
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string userId, string code)
    {
        if (userId == null || code == null)
        {
            return View("Error");
        }
        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return View("Error");
        }
        var result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, code);
        return View(result.Succeeded ? "ConfirmEmail" : "Error");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Show logout page
    /// </summary>
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Logout(string logoutId)
    {
        var vm = new LogoutViewModel
        {
            LogoutId = logoutId
        };

        return View(vm);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handle logout page postback
    /// </summary>
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Logout(LogoutViewModel model)
    {
        var user = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
        var subjectId = HttpContext.User.Identity.GetSubjectId();

        // delete authentication cookie
        await HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync();


        // set this so UI rendering sees an anonymous user
        HttpContext.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity());

        // get context information (client name, post logout redirect URI and iframe for federated signout)
        var logout = await _interaction.GetLogoutContextAsync(model.LogoutId);

         var vm = new LoggedOutViewModel
        {
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = logout?.PostLogoutRedirectUri,
            ClientName = logout?.ClientId,
            SignOutIframeUrl = logout?.SignOutIFrameUrl
        };


        await _persistedGrantService.RemoveAllGrantsAsync(subjectId, "angular2client");

        return View("LoggedOut", vm);
    }

    #region Helpers

    private void AddErrors(IdentityResult result)
    {
        foreach (var error in result.Errors)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
        }
    }

    private Task<ApplicationUser> GetCurrentUserAsync()
    {
        return _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
    }

    private IActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
    {
        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
        {
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

_signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() is failing because Identity does not know the schema you are using. You have to create a method based similar to GetExternalLoginInfoAsync extracting your info.

```cs
private async Task<ExternalLoginInfo> AuthenticationManager_GetExternalLoginInfoAsync_Workaround()
        {
            ExternalLoginInfo loginInfo = null;
            var info = await HttpContext.Authentication.GetAuthenticateInfoAsync(IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme);
            var auth = new AuthenticateContext(IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme);
            // read external identity from the temporary cookie
            await HttpContext.Authentication.AuthenticateAsync(auth);

            if (auth.Principal == null || auth.Properties == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("External authentication error");
            }

            // retrieve claims of the external user
            var claims = auth.Principal.Claims.ToList();


            // try to determine the unique id of the external user - the most common claim type for that are the sub claim and the NameIdentifier
            // depending on the external provider, some other claim type might be used
            var userIdClaim = claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == JwtClaimTypes.Subject);
            if (userIdClaim == null)
            {
                userIdClaim = claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
            }
            if (userIdClaim == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Unknown userid");
            }

            string userObjectID = auth.Principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
            // remove the user id claim from the claims collection and move to the userId property
            // also set the name of the external authentication provider
            claims.Remove(userIdClaim);
            var provider = userIdClaim.Issuer;
            var userId = userIdClaim.Value;

            var displayName = auth.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.GivenName);

            AuthenticationProperties props = null;


            loginInfo = new ExternalLoginInfo(auth.Principal, userIdClaim.Issuer, userIdClaim.Value, displayName)         

            return loginInfo;
        }
```

And i added this on the ExternalLoginCallback

```
  var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (info == null)
        {
            info = await AuthenticationManager_GetExternalLoginInfoAsync_Workaround();
            if (info == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));
            }

        }
```

Hope it helps, its a work in progress still.